# I have a column with active and inactive elements in same column; I need split active and inactive separately

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have table called `History` with columns `id, actiondate, status`.

| ID | ActionDate | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 4/22/2021 | active |
| 11 | 4/25/2021 | Deactive |

I need to show to user like activedate and deactivedate in separate columns in Oracle for one ID.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   history
PIVOT (
  MAX( ActionDate )
  FOR Status IN (
    'active' As active,
    'Deactive' AS deactive
  )
)
```

or conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT id,
       MAX( CASE status WHEN 'active' THEN ActionDate END ) AS active,
       MAX( CASE status WHEN 'Deactive' THEN ActionDate END ) AS Deactive
FROM   history
GROUP BY
       id;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE history ( ID, ActionDate, Status ) AS
SELECT 11, DATE '2021-04-22', 'active' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, DATE '2021-04-25', 'Deactive' FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

> | ID | ACTIVE | DEACTIVE |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 11 | 2021-04-22 00:00:00 | 2021-04-25 00:00:00 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2d8324a2f9a01a2ce888281063c224cd)*